# Extracting record from big endian data

Tags: ada, endianness, gnat

I have the following code for network protocol implementation. As the protocol is big endian, I wanted to use the *Bit_Order* attribute and *High_Order_First* value but it seems I made a mistake.

```ada
With Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with System; use System;

procedure Bit_Extraction is

   type Byte is range 0 .. (2**8)-1 with Size => 8;

   type Command is (Read_Coils,
                    Read_Discrete_Inputs
                   ) with Size => 7;

   for Command use (Read_Coils => 1,
                    Read_Discrete_Inputs => 4);

   type has_exception is new Boolean with Size => 1;

    type Frame is record
      Function_Code : Command;
      Is_Exception : has_exception := False;
   end record
     with Pack => True,
     Size => 8;

   for Frame use
      record
         Function_Code at 0 range 0 .. 6;
         Is_Exception at 0 range 7 .. 7;
      end record;

   for Frame'Bit_Order use High_Order_First;
   for Frame'Scalar_Storage_Order use High_Order_First;

   function To_Frame is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Byte, Frame);

   my_frame : Frame;
begin
   my_frame := To_Frame (Byte'(16#32#)); -- Big endian version of 16#4#
   Put_Line (Command'Image (my_frame.Function_Code)
             & " "
             & has_exception'Image (my_frame.Is_Exception));
end Bit_Extraction;
```

Compilation is ok but the result is

```
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : bit_extraction.adb:39 invalid data
```

What did I forget or misunderstand ?

**UPDATE**

The real record in fact is

```ada
type Frame is record
      Transaction_Id : Transaction_Identifier;
      Protocol_Id : Word := 0;
      Frame_Length : Length;
      Unit_Id : Unit_Identifier;
      Function_Code : Command;
      Is_Exception : Boolean := False;    
end record with Size => 8 * 8, Pack => True;

for Frame use
      record
         Transaction_Id at 0 range 0 .. 15;
         Protocol_Id at 2 range 0 .. 15;
         Frame_Length at 4 range 0 .. 15;
         Unit_id at 6 range 0 .. 7;
         Function_Code at 7 range 0 .. 6;
         Is_Exception at 7 range 7 .. 7;
      end record;
```

Where *Transaction_Identifier*, *Word* and *Length* are 16-bit wide.

These ones are displayed correctly if I remove the *Is_Exception* field and extend *Function_Code* to 8 bits.

The dump of the frame to decode is as following:

```
00000000  00 01 00 00 00 09 11 03  06 02 2b 00 64 00 7f
```

So my only problem is really to extract the 8th bit of the last byte.

Comment: are you sure about needing `Bit_Order` ? network convention is big endian on the bytes, not on the bits. You probably just need Scalar_Storage_Order.

Comment: It's only an extract of the real record. In the real one, there are field which are size of a word that's the reason why I thought I would need it but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre moreover you can't set *Scalar_Storage_Order* to a value different from the *Bit_Order* one which is the case there.

Comment: I just don't agree with `Byte'(16#32#)); -- Big endian version of 16#4#`. Big or little endian affect bytes, not bits. At the byte level, there's no endianness

Comment: Right but it doesn't work with 16#4# nether

Comment: I have seen it done before, will have to dust off memory on how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong.

In fact, the [Modbus Ethernet Frame definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Frame_format) mentioned that, in case of exception, the returned code should be the function code plus 128 (0x80) (see [explanation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Exception_responses)). That's the reason why I wanted to represent it through a *Boolean* value but my representation clauses were wrong.

The correct clauses are these ones :

```ada
   for Frame use
      record
         Transaction_Id at 0 range 0 .. 15;
         Protocol_Id at 2 range 0 .. 15;
         Frame_Length at 4 range 0 .. 15;
         Unit_id at 6 range 0 .. 7;
         Is_Exception at 6 range 8 .. 8;
         Function_Code at 6 range 9 .. 15;
      end record;
```

This way, the Modbus network protocol is correctly modelled (or not but at least, my code is working).

I really thank [egilhh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56661585/1677089) and [simonwright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56661993/1677089) for making me find what was wrong and explain the semantics behind the aspects.

Obviously, I don't know who reward :)

Answer (score 5):

So,

```ada
    for Frame use
      record
         Transaction_Id at 0 range 0 .. 15;
         Protocol_Id at 2 range 0 .. 15;
         Frame_Length at 4 range 0 .. 15;
         Unit_id at 6 range 0 .. 7;
         Function_Code at 7 range 0 .. 6;
         Is_Exception at 7 range 7 .. 7;
      end record;
```

It seems you want Is_Exception to be the the LSB of the last byte?
With `for Frame'Bit_Order use System.High_Order_First;` the LSB will be bit 7,

(also, `16#32#` will never be `-- Big endian version of 16#4#`, the bit pattern just doesn't match)

It may be more intuitive and clear to specify all of your fields relative to the word they're in, rather than the byte:

```ada
         Unit_ID at 6 range 0..7;
         Function_Code at 6 range 8 .. 14;
         Is_Exception at 6 range 15 .. 15;
```

Given the definition of `Command` above, the legal values for the last byte will then be:

- 2 -> READ_COILS FALSE
- 3 -> READ_COILS TRUE
- 8 -> READ_DISCRETE_INPUTS FALSE
- 9 -> READ_DISCRETE_INPUTS TRUE

BTW,
by applying your update to your original program, and adding/changing the following, you program works for me

add

```ada
    with Interfaces;
```

add

```ada
    type Byte_Array is array(1..8) of Byte with Pack;
```

change, since we don't know the definition

```ada
    Transaction_ID : Interfaces.Unsigned_16;
    Protocol_ID : Interfaces.Unsigned_16; 
    Frame_Length : Interfaces.Unsigned_16;
    Unit_ID : Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
```

change

```ada
    function To_Frame is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Byte_Array, Frame);
```

change

```ada
    my_frame := To_Frame (Byte_Array'(00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 09, 16#11#, 16#9#));
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got it thanks to you and Simon's layout

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [AdaCore post on bit order and byte order](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-140-bridging-the-endianness-gap) to see how they handle it. After reading that, you will probably find that the bit order of your frame value is really 16#08#, which probably is not what you are expecting.

Big Endian / Little Endian typically refers to Byte order rather than bit order, so when you see that Network protocols are Big Endian, they mean Byte order.  Avoid setting Bit_Order for your records.  In modern systems, you will almost never need that.

Your record is only one byte in size, so byte order won't matter for it by itself.  Byte order comes into play when you have larger field values (>8 bits long).

Comment: I already read it and still can't find a way to make it work. When you set *Scalar_Storage_Order* to *High_Order_First*, you have to also put *Bit_Order* to the same value. If not, there's a compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

Your original record declaration works fine (GNAT complains about the `Pack`, `warning: pragma Pack has no effect, no unplaced components`). The problem is with working out the little-endian `Byte`.

```
---------------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |    BE bit numbers
---------------------------------
| c   c   c   c   c   c   c | e |
---------------------------------
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |    LE bit numbers
---------------------------------
```

so if you want the `Command` to be `Read_Discrete_Inputs`, the `Byte` needs to have BE bit 4 (LE bit 3) set i.e. LE `16#8#`.

Comment: I added the *Pack* pragme because I was using *Boolean* in the first place. Now that I use a new type specifying the *Size* aspect, I think it's enough

Answer (score 0):

The bit_order pragma doesn't reverse the order that the bits appear in memory. It simply defines whether the most significant bit (left most) will be logically referred to as zero (High_Order_First) or the least significant bit will be referred to as zero (Low_Order_First) when interpreting the First_Bit and Last_Bit offsets from the byte position in the representation clause. Keep in mind that these offsets are taken from the MSB or LSB of the scalar the record component belongs to AS A VALUE. So in order for the byte positions to carry the same meaning on a little endian CPU as they do on a big endian CPU (as well as the in memory representation of multibyte machine scalars, which exist when one or more record components with the same byte position have a last_bit value which exceeds the capacity of a single byte) then 'Scalar_Storage_Order must *also* be specified.