# Ada - how to explicitly pack a bit-field record type?

Tags: stream, record, ada, bit-fields

Please consider the following experimental Ada program which attempts to create a 32-bit record with well defined bit fields, create one and output it to a file stream...

```
with System;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Streams.Stream_Io; use Ada.Streams.Stream_Io;

procedure Main is

   type Bit is mod    (2 ** 1);

   type Opcode_Number is mod (2 ** 4);
   type Condition_Number is mod (2 ** 4);
   type Operand is mod (2 ** 9);

   type RAM_Register is
      record
         Opcode : Opcode_Number;
         Z      : Bit;
         C      : Bit;
         R      : Bit;
         I      : Bit;
         Cond   : Condition_Number;
         Rsvd_1 : Bit;
         Rsvd_2 : Bit;
         Dest   : Operand;
         Src    : Operand;
      end record;

   for RAM_Register use
      record
         Opcode at 0 range 28 .. 31;
         Z      at 0 range 27 .. 27;
         C      at 0 range 26 .. 26;
         R      at 0 range 25 .. 25;
         I      at 0 range 24 .. 24;
         Cond   at 0 range 20 .. 23;
         Rsvd_1 at 0 range 19 .. 19;
         Rsvd_2 at 0 range 18 .. 18;
         Dest   at 0 range  9 .. 17;
         Src    at 0 range  0 ..  8;
      end record;
   for RAM_Register'Size use 32;
   for RAM_Register'Bit_Order use System.High_Order_First;

   --  ADA 2012 language reference 'full_type_declaration'
   --  (page 758, margin number 8/3) for RAM_Register
   pragma Atomic (RAM_Register);


   --   3         2         1         0
   --  10987654321098765432109876543210
   --  OOOOzcriCONDrrDDDDDDDDDsssssssss

   X : RAM_Register := (2#1000#,
                           2#1#,
                           2#1#,
                           2#1#,
                           2#1#,
                        2#1000#,
                           2#1#,
                           2#1#,
                   2#100000001#,
                   2#100000001#);

   The_File : Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.File_Type;
   The_Stream : Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.Stream_Access;

begin
   begin
      Open (The_File, Out_File, "test.dat");
   exception
      when others =>
         Create (The_File, Out_File, "test.dat");
   end;

   The_Stream := Stream (The_File);
   RAM_Register'Write (The_Stream, X);
   Close (The_File);
end Main;
```

I used the info here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Object_serialization#Ada and here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Attributes/%27Bit_Order (the very last example) to create the above.

Running the code and examining the output with `xxd -g1 test.dat` gives the following 12 bytes of output...

```
00000000: 08 01 01 01 01 08 01 01 01 01 01 01              ............
```

**QUESTION:**

How can this 32 bit record be written to, or read from, a stream as 32 bits, observing all bitfield positions?  Imagine I was communicating with a microcontroller on an RS-232 port, each bit will be required to be exactly in the right place at the right time.  The syntax `for RAM_Register use record...` seems to have had no effect on how `'Write` arranges its output.

If I do provide my own `'Read` and `'Write` implementations, doesn't that **directly** contradict the 'for RAM_Register use record...` code?

Comment: You could legally make your own stream attributes that converted to/from XML on the wire.  The rep clause defines layout in register/store, & if you want to send that on the wire that’s what you should do (with unchecked conversion at the lower levels). Ada streams are a much higher-level construct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably will have to convert the instance to an unsigned integer (via an unchecked conversion) and then write the unsigned integer to the stream. The default implementation of `Write` ignores the representation clause (see also [RM 13 9/3](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-13-2.html#p9)):

> For composite types, the Write or Read attribute for each component is called in canonical order, [...]

So, add

```
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
```

and define `RAM_Register` as

```
   type RAM_Register is
      record
         Opcode : Opcode_Number;
         Z      : Bit;
         C      : Bit;
         R      : Bit;
         I      : Bit;
         Cond   : Condition_Number;
         Rsvd_1 : Bit;
         Rsvd_2 : Bit;
         Dest   : Operand;
         Src    : Operand;
      end record with Atomic;  

   procedure Write
     (Stream : not null access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class;
      Item   : RAM_Register);

   for RAM_Register'Write use Write;

   for RAM_Register use
      record         
         Opcode at 0 range 28 .. 31;
         Z      at 0 range 27 .. 27;
         C      at 0 range 26 .. 26;
         R      at 0 range 25 .. 25;
         I      at 0 range 24 .. 24;
         Cond   at 0 range 20 .. 23;
         Rsvd_1 at 0 range 19 .. 19;
         Rsvd_2 at 0 range 18 .. 18;
         Dest   at 0 range  9 .. 17;
         Src    at 0 range  0 ..  8;
      end record;   

   for RAM_Register'Size use 32;
   for RAM_Register'Bit_Order use System.High_Order_First; 

   -----------
   -- Write --
   -----------

   procedure Write
     (Stream : not null access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class;
      Item   : RAM_Register)
   is

      function To_Unsigned_32 is
        new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (RAM_Register, Unsigned_32); 

      U32 : Unsigned_32 := To_Unsigned_32 (Item);

   begin   
      Unsigned_32'Write (Stream, U32);        
   end Write;
```

This yields

```
$ xxd -g1 test.dat
00000000: 01 03 8e 8f                                      ....
```

*Note: the bitorder may have been reversed as I had to comment the aspect specification `for RAM_Register'Bit_Order use System.High_Order_First;`*

Comment: Your `xxd` output matches my pen-and-paper workings except for the byte swapping!  I can compensate for that.  I hadn't expected to have to resort to "unchecked" shenanigans for something like this.  The official documentation is very hard to follow and understand in this regard.  Thanks.

Comment: I already had problem with endianess and you should find hints in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656184/extracting-record-from-big-endian-data However, you will see that I use a Gnat only attribute for this.